# How to select elements in HTMl using JS and why is function not working in this case?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am doing a vanilla JS practice and I ran into some trouble with the function which i don't know why. The editor kept saying "can't read property of undefined" but i am using the correct selectors and methods so i don't get what's wrong. Here'ss the code

js:

```
function opena(){
  var eleme= document.getElementsByClassName(".left")[0]
  var elemo = document.getElementsByClassName(".right")[0]

    eleme.classList.add("applejuice");

   elemo.classList.add("pearjuice")
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <button onClick="opena()">press</button>
  <div class="pack">
    <div class="left" >A</div>
    <div class ="right">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show how did you add the script in HTML?

Comment: you do not have to user .left as it is class name use only "left"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), you do not need to put `.` before each classname like `.left` or `.right`. You can use is directly like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("left")
document.getElementsByClassName("right")
```

```js
function opena() {
  var eleme = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0]
  var elemo = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0]

  eleme.classList.add("applejuice");
  elemo.classList.add("pearjuice")
}
```

```css
.applejuice { color: red; }
.pearjuice { color: orange; }
```

```html
<body>
  <button onClick="opena()">press</button>
  <div class="pack">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="right">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

On a side note, `.` before the class name would have been required if you were using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like:

```js
function opena() {
  var eleme = document.querySelectorAll(".left")[0]
  var elemo = document.querySelectorAll(".right")[0]

  eleme.classList.add("applejuice");
  elemo.classList.add("pearjuice")
}
```

```css
.applejuice { color: red; }
.pearjuice { color: orange; }
```

```html
<body>
  <button onClick="opena()">press</button>
  <div class="pack">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="right">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass in the class name you want to get.

```
var eleme= document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0]
var elemo = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0]
```